# SQL Server : stating temp table exists, but it's not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I'm using the following to check for and create a table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tempdb' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '#tmp_items%')
    CREATE TABLE #tmp_items 
    (
        id               INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        inv_mast_uid     INT DEFAULT NULL,
        src_invoice      BIT DEFAULT NULL,
        src_invoice_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
        src_order        BIT DEFAULT NULL,
        src_order_date   DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
    )
ELSE
    TRUNCATE TABLE #tmp_items
```

I get the following error:

> There is already an object named '#tmp_items' in the database.

If it existed, it should have truncated the table....

When I look at `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, I don't see anything:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Returns:

```
ssb
UTIL
mbl
DataSync
dbo

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tmp_items%'
```

Returns nothing.

It doesn't make sense, and I'm at a loss...  I have even disconnected from the server (which should have purged the temp tables) and reconnected and still get the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: As I recall in SQL Server, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is only looking at your current database, but the temporary table is stored in the temporary database.  I think `OBJECT_ID()` is often used to check for existence.

Comment: It was my understanding that INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the preferred way to do it.  Yes, it looks at the current database, but the table schema is tempdb, which is under the current database.

Comment: Can you use this and check what is the response?

    use tempdb
    go

    select *
    from   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where  TABLE_CATALOG = 'tempdb'
    and    TABLE_NAME like '#tmp_items%'
    go

Comment: The columns TABLE_SCHEMA has nothing to do with which database the table belongs to. It is the schema that table belongs to. And it should never be used to check the schema because it is not always correct. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 The default schema for objects is dbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to struggle with conditionally truncating or creating a temp table like this no matter how you slice it. Change this to drop the temp table if it exists and then always create it. This is much simpler.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_items%') is not null
    drop table #tmp_items

CREATE TABLE #tmp_items 
(
    id                  int         identity(1,1),
    inv_mast_uid        int         DEFAULT NULL,
    src_invoice         bit         DEFAULT NULL,
    src_invoice_date    datetime    DEFAULT NULL,
    src_order           bit         DEFAULT NULL,
    src_order_date      datetime    DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: Ok, that works.  I used to use OBJECT_ID but I was told that using INFORMATION_SCHEMA was the "preferred" way now.  Is that not true, or is OBJECT_ID preferred only for temp tables?

Comment: I wouldn't use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to check for the existence of any object. Not sure who said that or why they think that is correct. Please note that in the MS documentation they even say they are not accurate. They are there for backwards compatibility. "INFORMATION_SCHEMA views could be incomplete since they are not updated for all new features." There are in fact many reasons NOT to use them for anything. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Comment: @SeanLange, I upvoted your comment and your answer, but in the spirit of full disclosure, I use INFORMATION_SCHEMA far too often (though never for object existence). Usually for column lists.